# How to write a method decorated with @defer.inlineCallbacks that may or may not yield?

Tags: python, twisted

My method is of the following form:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def myAsyncMethod():
    if someCondition:
        yield anotherAsyncMethod()
```

The problem is that if `someCondition` is not `True` then no yield happens and this essentially becomes a synchronous function. The decorator then causes this to be an error.

Right now, I am just doing `yield 1` at the end of it. is that the right thing to do here?
I could of course do:

```
d = Deferred()
d.callback(0)
yield d
```

But I don't see how that is any different

Edit: What I meant here is that if I try to do `yield myAsyncMethod()` then it would generate an exception. I dont want to have to handle the exception. One way to avoid it is to just yield something at the end of myAsyncMethod(), but is there another no-hacky way of doing this. What is the common practice here?

Comment: As Jean-Paul's answer indicates: no, this is wrong.  Can you elaborate on why you thought this would be the case?  Perhaps some actual, runnable code that caused a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The premise is incorrect.  Consider:

```
>>> def foo():
...     if False:
...             yield
... 
>>> foo()
<generator object foo at 0x7f579cc4ccd0>
>>>
```

Here, the yield statement is never evaluated.  This doesn't stop `foo` from returning a generator, though.

This means that you can decorate such a function with `inlineCallbacks` without any problem.

```
>>> @inlineCallbacks
... def foo():
...     if False:
...             yield
... 
>>> foo()
<Deferred at 0x7f08328e3ef0  current result: None>
>>>
```

Since the generator has no elements, what you get back is a `Deferred` that already has `None` as a result, as you can see here.

Further, this means you can call such a function and yield it from another `inlineCallbacks`-decorated function without problems:

```
>>> @inlineCallbacks
... def bar():
...     print "Foo result is:", (yield foo())
... 
>>> bar()
Foo result is: None
<Deferred at 0x7f08328e3ef0  current result: None>
>>>
```

Here you see that `bar` executed, yielded the result of calling `foo`, printed out the result of that `Deferred`, and then completed with its own `Deferred` (which also already has a `None` result).

Comment: Thanks Jean-Paul! I didnt know that this was the case. However, I have added some more detail in my question about exactly what I am seeking here.

Comment: I expanded the answer a bit to try to explain more completely.